# Flutter Firebase add a company to a user

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

So users can add projects and other users can see and edit them aswell but I only want the users of the same company or group to see his projects obviously. so I do have a streambuilder which streams the tasks of a firebase database but as it is now everyone can see everyones task how do I add a check for the users company?
it also needs this check when creating a task so when I create it I want it to save what company it got created if that makes sense.

would be nice if anyone could help me out with this

I expected it to create the task the user created as it does right now but I have to add a company or group check to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add '*group*' field to each user and task.

For example, when you create a user

```
final uid = "userID123";

final usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");
    
final user1 = <String, dynamic>{
   "name": "john doe",
   "idNo": 128101,
    ...
   "group": "developer",
};
    
usersRef.doc(uid).set(user1);
```

And create a task

```
final taskID = "taskID123";

final taskRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");
        
 final task1 = <String, dynamic>{
    "name": "refactoring",
     ...
    "group": "developer",
 };
        
    taskRef.doc(taskID).set(task1);
```

And then, when you stream tasks for each user, use a query filter task based on the group in which the user belongs to

```
final taskGroupStream =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("cities").where("group", isEqualTo: user1['group']).snapshots();
```

Use this stream inside your StreamBuilder widget.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes ty solved my problem :D